# How do I find the number of local minima of a loss function?

Tags: time-series, self-study, optimization, nonlinear-regression, loss-functions

Consider the loss function $L(A_1, ω_1, ..., A_d, ω_d)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1} ^{m}(Y_j-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1} ^{d}A_k\sin(ω_kt_j))^2$ used to fit a time series to a sum of simple oscillations with frequencies $ω_j$ and amplitudes $A_j$. $L$ has a local minimizer with distinct frequencies.

How can I find the number of local minima if I increase $d$ (for example $d=3$, $d=4$, $d=5$, ...)?

Comment: I understand but disagree with the votes to migrate to Math.SE. Working with loss functions is squarely on-topic here, and discussions related to the statistical problem at hand are more likely to benefit the OP than discussions related to the calculus. // Have you tried doing the calculus?

Comment: How are $n$ and $j$ related?  What are the values of the $t_j$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @whuber made a correction to the post and changed n to j, $t_j$ is the time value when the observation $Y_j$ is made

Comment: @Sycorax I have tried differentiating the function and finding where the first order derivative is 0, and seeing if the second order derivative is positive at those critical points (where the first derivative is 0). I am stuck trying to find anything (if it exists) from the function that implies strict descent or something else that shows every critical point is a local minima. Since I know that have $d$ parameters will give me $2d$ critical points.

Comment: Great, this is good information to have because it helps answer-writers understand what you need help with. Please [edit] to add this information to the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Once you've done this, the question will be suitable for reopening.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be impossible for every critical point (zero derivative) to be a local minimum, at least assuming smoothness? Maybe my intuition from functions from the reals to the reals is clouding my judgment, but I would expect that to be true for high-dimension functions, too.